# How to get portlet preferences in grails for liferay?

Tags: grails, liferay, portlet

How to get portlet preferences in grails for liferay .??

I used :

```
import javax.portlet.*

 def renderEdit = {
      PortletPreferences pref = RenderRequest.getPreferences()
      println pref
        ['mykey':'myvalue']
  }
```

but getting issue :

> No signature of method: static
>   javax.portlet.RenderRequest.getPreferences()
>   is applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: []

Comment: Please format your code using the `{}` button in the editor, rather than by using <br> tags everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying RenderRequest.getPreferences(). There is no such method for **class** RenderRequest. Try calling the **instance**:

```
renderRequest.getPreferences(); // notice the small first letter r in 'render..'
```

Comment: thanks heikkim , I used PortletPreferences pref = portletRequest.getPreferences() and this worked good .